# JCommander argument doesn't work in Docker ENTRYPOINT

Tags: java, docker, jcommander

I have a standard JCommander parameter which works fine when running the jar locally or through IntelliJ, but as soon as I try and load it through a dockerfile it returns:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException: Was passed main parameter '-profile ${PROFILE}' but no main parameter was defined in your arg class
```

The code I'm loading the args through:

```
@Data
public static class Args {

    @Parameter(
            names = {"-profile", "-p"},
            arity = 1,
            required = true)
    private String profile;
}
```

I'm parsing that via:

```
 JCommander.newBuilder().addObject(ARGS).build().parse(args);
```

The entry point command I have in my Dockerfile:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java" , "-jar", "/usr/app/app.jar", "-profile ${PROFILE}"]
```

Finally I'm just starting the container the usual way with `...-e PROFILE=dev`

Is there something obvious I've missed here, do I just need to escape quotes somewhere or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an obvious mistake which took longer than I care to admit to spot. The correct way to pass arguments if of course

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java" , "-jar", "/usr/app/app.jar", "-profile", "${PROFILE}"]
```

Note the comma between the key `-profile` and its value `${PROFILE}`.